# Identify the imagery date of Google satellite picture in QGIS

Tags: qgis, wms, google-earth, date, quickmapservices

I am using the Quick Map Services Plugin in QGIS. Is there a way to find out the date of the aerial image in QGIS ? I used to check Google Earth Pro and take the imagery date from the latest picture in Google Earth Pro. But I just discovered that apparently the WMS plugin doesn't show always the latest image that is shown in Google Earth...

Comment: Only in Google Earth - The web/browser version highlights updated areas https://earth.google.com/web/@38.5246139,94.17548462,3306.39479657a,14140969.00008917d,35y,0h,0t,0r/data=Ci4SLBIgOGQ2YmFjYjU2ZDIzMTFlOThiNTM2YjMzNGRiYmRhYTAiCGxheWVyc18w